# Standard toolchain / tasks to repair a Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair

A friend owns a **Lenovo notebook**.

The system sometime does not boot **Windows 7**. If this happens, a **black screen with a lifebelt** boots. I've never seen such a lifebelt screen on another system (Windows support isn't my daytime job).

After **several hours**, the system finally manages to boot Windows 7. After a **few days of normal work**, the notebook shows the lifebelt again. This screen comes from [Lenovo's Recue and Recovery](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-4Q2QAK) solution.

I'd like to know, which standard tools exist to

- **repair** the system
- or **identify** the problem reason

While this is probably a broad question, I'd be too happy to even receive **'simple' hints**.

But maybe there exists an application, which contains a good set of tools to assist. Does such a app exist?

A Windows DVD/CD isn't available, since the notebook comes with a **recovery partition**. Thus, the only option seems to **completely reset to shipped system state**.

In this case, I assume that no option exists, which allows to **save and later recover the state of application programs** - after the complete reset. Am I right?

Comment: I would urge them to contact Lenovo support. If the notebook is not under warranty, I would wipe and reimage/reinstall.

Comment: Thx!The system is assumed to be 3 years old. Thus it is not covered by a warranty.

Comment: Feel free to read our FAQ and learn why this is off topic for at least two reasons.

Comment: Many Lenovo notebooks are covered for 3 years so don't assume it is out of warrenty without checking.  You can aslo request copies of the restore media from Lenovo as well for a small charge if it is needed.

Comment: The lifebelt is Lenovo's software: http://support.lenovo.com/ContentResources/images/rnr_startup_screen.gif

Comment: This it is Lenovo's solution: http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-4Q2QAK

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar instance several years ago. Turned out to be Vundo related. Try Vundo fix. It may also be a memory issue from what I recall when researching my issue. Also, much can be said for a physical internal inspection and cleaning. Does it run hot?